# UIView is not removed from superview

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview

I`m having problem with removing view from superview.
Adding view:

```
- (void)createCircles
{
    NSString *currentDate = [self currentDate];
    NSArray *array = [self.horizontalScroll subviews];
    UILabel *label = nil;
    for (label in array)
    {
        if ([label.text isEqualToString:currentDate])
        {
            UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:label.frame];
            view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
            [self.horizontalScroll insertSubview:view atIndex:0];
            [self.labelsArray insertObject:view atIndex:0];
        }
    }
}
```

Trying to remove:

```
- (void)labelTouch:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender
{
    NSArray *array = [self.horizontalScroll subviews];
    UILabel *label = (UILabel*)sender.view;
    for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; ++i)
    {
        UILabel *l = array[i];
        if (label.tag == l.tag)
        {
            UIView *view = nil;
            view = [self.labelsArray objectAtIndex:0];
            view.hidden = YES;
            [view removeFromSuperview];
            view = nil;
            [self.labelsArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        }
    }
}
```

But after touch view is still displaying. Tried to remove label (l) - it is removed

Comment: (1) it looks like you're searching for a `tag` but I don't see where you're setting it.  (2) Instead of searching through subviews you can just use `[UIView -viewWithTag:]` to get that view.  (3)  If you're removing the superview (the UILabel) you don't need to remove its subviews.

Comment: I`m setting tag in another method. I cannot remove view that is added to array

Comment: What's the result of `NSLog(@"targetTag: %d, subviewTags: %@", label.tag, [array valueForKey:@"tag"]);`? Is the target tag actually contained in the subview tags?

Comment: Works with answer of Akhilrajtr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
 [[[self.horizontalScroll subviews] objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperView];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should store reference to this "unkillable" view in ivar or property. Initialize it in first method and call removeFromSupperView in second.

Comment: But I did similar with putting it in array